# Disable url access of files

Tags: php, mysql, url, redirect

I am using WAMP and hosting the PHP files locally.

Assume i have these two files.

**customer.php**- A form to add customer details

**recordCustomer.php**- Connects to the database and store the information in the database(where all the processing is done)

How do I stop a user from accessing the file **recordCustomer.php** by typing the file name in the address bar.

```
http://localhost/testing/recordCustomer.php has to be redirected and given an error message
```

However

```
http://localhost/testing/customer.php is allowed
```

Thank you

Comment: Do your users log in to your page? do you uses session then?

Comment: Yes. The system has different user levels and users need to be logged in. I just need to give them an error message if the try to access a file where data processing is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the access to `recordCustomer.php` but the fact that you execute the code if the access is direct.
Preventing the access by htaccess for example, will make your form unsubmitable.

You should use an random token in your `customer.php` form. The token is saved into session and inserted into the form with a hidden input.

On `recordCustomer.php` you just have to check if the token is given and if it match the one in session.

If it match => this is a legit call to `recordCustomer.php`
else => try to bypass your form , reject the request.

That's a school case of CSRF attack ;)

Have a look [here](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2008/10/16/how-to-csrf-protect-all-your-forms/) for example

Comment: Using a token in a hidden input field an checking like you said worked, however i guess I have to use that in all my forms :(.. Thanks for your help, really appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to block access to the entire **recordCustomer.php**, you just need to check at start of **recordCustomer.php** if the user who is calling the page has the permission to modify the records he is sending in the form. If not then show an error.

I paste you some code so you get the idea.

Pseudo/php code for **recordCustomer.php**:

```
if (! isset($_SESSION['user_logged'])) {
    echo 'You have to be logged in to access this page (this incident will be logged)';
    exit;
}

$user = $_SESSION['user_logged']; //this was saved when the user logged in
$record = $_POST['record_to_modify'];

if (!user_can_modify_record($user, $record)) {
    echo 'You dont have permission to access that record (this incident will be logged)';
    exit;
}

//HERE THE REST OF recordCustomer.php

function user_can_modify_record($user, $record) {
   $set = db_query("select user from table where user = '". $user. "' and record_id = ". $record);
   return db_count_rows($set) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if the file is being requested from a form by checking:

`if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: This could easily be faked by a malicious and tech-savvy user.

Comment: The question asks "how to show error if page is accessed directly". I think this is an easy way to achieve that. Besides, the accepted solution can also be easily faked by a malicious and tech-savvy user.